# iPhone 5s home button and on-screen home button unreliable

Tags: iphone

The home button on a friend's iPhone 5s has become unreliable. It responds maybe one time out of twenty.

Till she could visit an Apple Store to get them to check it, I enabled the AssistiveTouch option to give her an on-screen home button. But the on-screen home button is similarly unreliable, only responding a fraction of the time. Other buttons on the AssistiveTouch control work fine.

Given that the on-screen home button is also unreliable this suggests it isn't a hardware problem. Has any seen this before? Can anyone suggest what the cause could be or how to resolve it?

Comment: Software version? Could this have started right after a software update? Have you tried basic troubleshooting (cycling Wifi on/off, removing SIM card, turning bluetooth & hotspot off, restarting phone, etc.)?

Comment: maybe it's because the iOS version is high (maybe 9) and the processor can't keep up with it.

Comment: @Hackman The phone is otherwise fine. Obviously it's not as fast as a current gen phone but it is perfectly usable, aside from the issues with the hardware / software buttons.

Comment: @owlswipe Not sure when this started, but the phone has since had at least one software update. It's been power cycled multiple times. Turning off/on Wifi/Bluetooth/etc made no difference.

Comment: OK, I think the best suggestion is to just contact Apple at https://getsupport.apple.com, they'll try to fix it and if they can't they'll just hook your friend up with a free replacement.

Comment: @owlswipe That's probably what'll end up happening, I was just hoping for some insight into why the on-screen button would be affected by the hardware button being faulty. The first time she visited the local store they were talking about replacing the whole screen assembly for over £100+. Which is frustrating when the screen itself seems fine.